# I have B1/B2 Visa. Can I travel for Business trip to US with this Visa?

Tags: visas, usa, b1-b2-visas

I have been given B1/B2 Visa, but first time when I had applied, it  was for vacation & holiday. Now I need to go to US for business meetings. Is this Visa good enough or do I have to apply for a B1 Visa again?

*Note*: I originally applied for vacation purposes, but in my visa it is stamped "R b1/b2"

Answer (score 8):

Yes, you can.

The US has two main types of "Visitor Visa" - B1 and B2, where B-1 is a "Temporary Business Visitor" visa and "B2" is a "Temporary Tourism Visitor" visa.

Rather than forcing people to apply for both types of visa if they intend to visit multiple times for different purposes, these two visas are frequently issued together, as a "B1/B2" visa, which is what you have.  This visa allows you to enter the USA for any purpose covered by either the B1 and/or B2 visas, for the duration of the visa.

Answer (score 5):

If your visa is still valid and it reads B1/B2 then you can use it as a [B1 visa](http://www.uscis.gov/working-united-states/temporary-visitors-business/b-1-temporary-business-visitor).  You should not have any issue.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you aren't paid money in the US for your services, you should be fine.